# How to install python binding of pango and pangocairo in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pango, pangocairo

I'm pretty new to pango and pangecairo, but I'd like to install a python binding of pango and pangocairo. I've installed pango, pangocffi, pangocairocffi via pip but it still tells me that no module named when I try to import them in python. Btw, I also install libsdl-pango-dev via apt but it seems not working as well. I have been searching solutions for a few days but no luck. Could anyone help me with that? Really appreciate!

Comment: I'm using anaconda, so is there any way to install them via anaconda or pip?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have internet connection.

Then update your OS:

```bash
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Then install it with:

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y libpango-1.0-0
```

please if it works follow me plz

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work. Still show no module named 'pango'. And I'm using anaconda, is there any way to install them via conda?

Comment: `sudo apt-get -y install libcogl-pango-dev` worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 to solve: "No package `pango` found".